# How to get the URI of a file stored in a folder created with context.getDir(directoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

Let's say I create a file inside the private folder like this:

```
val dir = context.getDir("myDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val file = File(dir, "myFileName")
```

What should be the content of provider_path.xml?

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--for file created inside context.getFilesDir() directory-->
<files-path name="someDirectory" path="."/> 

<!--for files created inside "myDir" ???-->
</paths>
```

I know how to get the URI for a file created inside context.getFilesDir(),  but it is possible to get the URI of a file created inside another private directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be the content of provider_path.xml?

If you are referring to `FileProvider`, it does not support arbitrary locations, such as `getDir("myDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`. Either store your files in a supported location (e.g., a subdirectory off of `getFilesDir()`) or write your own `ContentProvider` to serve up the files from your custom directory.